# getting free(): invalid size when executing code

Tags: c, compiler-errors, process, pthreads

compiling with gcc hw2.c -o x -lpthread

```
free(): invalid size
free(): invalid size
free(): invalid size
nano infile.txt
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the file pointer maybe? the semaphores have been commented out to fix this issue first. All answers point to the pointer but switching things up isn't much help. I've tried compiling differently that doesn't help either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

//sem_t X;

void process(){
    //sem_open("X", O_CREAT,0777,0);
    int ret;
    int N = 1;
    pid_t pid;
    FILE* infile = fopen ("infile.txt", "r");

    for(int i = 0; i< 50; i++){
        fscanf (infile, "%d", &N);
        fclose (infile);
        printf("N: %d Process ID: %d",N,pid);
        infile = fopen("infile.txt", "w");
        N++;
        //sem_post(&X);
        fprintf(infile,"%d",N);
        fflush(infile);
        fclose(infile);
    }
    printf("\n");
    int c;
    //sem_getvalue(&X,&c);
    printf(" \n \n \n%d",c);
}
int main(){
    int pid, pid1, pid2;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        //child1, Last
        printf("Starting Process C: ");
        process();
    }
    else{
        pid1 = fork();
        if(pid1 == 0){
            //child2, Middle
            printf("Starting Process B: ");
            process();
        }
        else{
            pid2 = fork();
            if(pid2 == 0){
                //child 3, First
                printf("Starting Process A: ");
                process();
            }
            else{
            }
        }
        
    }
    //sem_close(&X);
    //sem_unlink(&X);
}
```

Comment: `sem_post(&X)`, `sem_close(&X);` etc result in Undefined Behaviour because you never set `X`. You should declare X as `sem_t *X` and assign it with `X = sem_open()`.

Comment: `printf("N: %d Process ID: %d",N,pid);` reads `pid` which is uninitialized. - You should also `waitpid` on your child processes to finish before you exit the parent process. I also recommend adding an `exit()` at the end of the `process()` function.

Comment: This is a runtime error, not a compiler error.

Comment: Btw, you don't need `-lpthread` for this but I do suggest `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors` and `-g -fsanitize=address` to spot errors more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious problem is in your loop. I've removed everything but the `fopen` and `fclose` calls:

```
FILE* infile = fopen ("infile.txt", "r");

for(int i = 0; i< 50; i++){
    fclose (infile);
    infile = fopen("infile.txt", "w");
    fclose(infile);
}
```

As you probably now see, when `i` is `1`, you try to `fclose(infile)` - but that isn't open, hence the errors you get.

You need to move the first `fopen` into the loop - and check that opening the file and reading from it succeeds too:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void process() {
    int N = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        FILE* infile = fopen("infile.txt", "r");
        if(infile) {
            bool readok = fscanf(infile, "%d", &N) == 1;
            fclose(infile);

            if(readok) { /* only do this if a value was read from the file ok */
                printf("N: %d Process ID: %d", N, getpid());
                infile = fopen("infile.txt", "w");
                if(infile) {
                    N++;
                    fprintf(infile, "%d", N);
                    fflush(infile);
                    fclose(infile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    exit(0); /* terminate this sub process */
}

int main() {
    const size_t kPids = 3;

    pid_t pids[kPids]; /* simplify keeping a number of background processes */

    for(size_t i = 0; i < kPids; ++i) {
        pids[i] = fork();
        if(pids[i] == 0) {
            printf("Starting Process %c:\n", (char)('A' + i));
            process();
        }
    }

    /* wait for children to finish */
    pid_t pid;
    int wstatus;
    while((pid = wait(&wstatus)) != -1) {
        printf("pid %d is done with status %d\n", pid, wstatus);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is problematic

```
FILE* infile = fopen ("infile.txt", "r"); //1

for(int i = 0; i< 50; i++){
    fscanf (infile, "%d", &N);
    fclose (infile); //2
    printf("N: %d Process ID: %d",N,pid);
    infile = fopen("infile.txt", "w"); //3
    N++;
    //sem_post(&X);
    fprintf(infile,"%d",N);
    fflush(infile);
    fclose(infile); //4
}
```

You open the file at `1`, then enter the loop, close it at `2`, re-open it at `3` and re-close it at `4`. In the next iteration, when you attempt to close at `2`, you would hit into a double-free as it's *already* been closed at `4`.